# window.addEventListener not being executed on click events

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, addeventlistener

This is a very basic Firefox addon , it opens a new `tab` and loads the specified `html` file.
It attachs a `ContentScript` to the `tab` but for some reason `alert('in event listener');` is never executed?
Although `alert('in script');` does run.
Whys that?

`main.js`

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

tabs.open({
  url: require('sdk/self').data.url('html/view.html'),
  isPinned: true,
  onOpen: function onOpen(tab) {

    console.log("onOpen");
    tab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: require('sdk/self').data.url('js/controller.js')
    });
  }
});
```

`controller.js`

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  alert('in event listener');

}, false);

alert('in script');
alert(document.getElementById("text").value);

// output
//   console.error: MyApp: 
//   Message: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

`view.html`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <textarea id="text">yo</textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine http://jsfiddle.net/D3FvU/ . Maybe you are doing event.stopPropagation somewhere further down but we don't know from this code

Comment: Have you tried it as a firefox addon? I see the jsfiddle works but the same code does not work when packaged as addon. And I am not calling `event.stopPropagation` anywhere

Comment: That's weird, try `document.addEventListener`

Comment: still no `alert` using `document.addEventListener`

Comment: change `onOpen` to `onReady`, maybe it needs to wait for document to load? not sure

Comment: changing to `onReady` did the trick with `window.addEventListener`, many thanks!

Comment: Let's move this to solution so it helps others when they run across the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moving to solution.

Change `onOpen` to `onReady` and instead of `document.addEventListener` use `window.addEventListener`. bobbyrne01 reports that it works, no clue why this fixed it though.